# fatal: cannot opendir 'folder': No such file or directory

Tags: git, bitbucket, windows-7-x64, tortoisegit

when i try to do a pull in my project i get this error

fatal: cannot opendir 'folder': No such file or directory

```
git.exe pull -v --no-rebase --progress "origin"

From bitbucket.org:...
= [up to date]      master     -> origin/master
fatal: cannot opendir 'folder ': No such file or directory

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 128)
```

Answer (score 2):

"windows" can not handle a file with empty names, so you must remove them from another platform "IOS" or "Linux" or directly through your web system "github" etc ...

Comment: Oh windows.... are you sure about the `.filename` though?... i coulda swore that was fine...

Comment: I just did a test, it is just files with empty names, i have to update my answer